# How to compute minimum number of operation required to make all the elements of sequence equal to each other

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

```
The problem is from a programming competition.
```

You are given two sequences `A (a1, a2, a3, ... an)` and `B (b1, b2, b3, ... bn)` of the same length `N`. In each step you can set `ai = ai - bi` if `ai >= bi`. Determine the minimum number of steps required to make all the numbers in `A` equal to each other.

**For Example**

```
A = {5, 7, 10, 5, 15} 
B = {2, 2, 1, 3, 5}
```

In the above example, the minimum number of steps required to make all the elements in `A` equal to each other is `8`.

```
A = {5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 90, 100}
B = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
```

In the above example, the minimum number of steps required to make all the elements in `A` equal to each other is `56`.

Do note that if it is not possible to make all the elements of the sequence `A` equal to each other then print `-1`.

**For Example**

```
A = {5, 6}  
B = {4, 3}
```

In the above case, the answer is `-1` because it is impossible to make all the elements of `A` equal to each other.

```
A = {5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 90, 100}
B = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5}
```

In the above case, the answer is `-1` because it is impossible to make all the elements of `A` equal to each other.

Could anyone can help me out on how to solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: Problem Statement: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/make-all-equal-90a21ab2/description/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target cannot be greater than the smallest element in `A`. If `m` is the index of the smallest element in `A`, the target must also be one of the values `A[m] - k * B[m]` (non-negative integer `k`). Since there may be duplicates of the smallest element in `A`, each with a different `b`, to simplify, we can just try all targets equal or smaller than `min(A)`.

We try them in a descending loop since clearly the highest valid one would take the least steps to reach. The check for validity, which must apply to all `(a, b)` pairs, given candidate target `t`:

```
(a - t) mod b == 0
```

Example:

```
A = {5, 7, 10, 5, 15}
B = {2, 2, 1, 3, 5}

t = 5

a's:

 5: 5 == 5
 7: (7 - 5) mod 2 == 0
10: (10 - 5) mod 1 == 0
 5: 5 == 5
15: (15 - 5) mod 5 == 0
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, B){
  const n = A.length;
  const m = Math.min(...A);
  let result;
  
  for (let t=m; t>=0; t--){
    result = 0;
    
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
      if ((A[i] - t) % B[i] == 0){
        result = result + (A[i] - t) / B[i];
        
      } else {
        result = -1;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (result > -1)
      return result;
  }
  
  return result;
}

var ABs = [
  [[5, 7, 10, 5, 15],
   [2, 2, 1, 3, 5]],

  [[5, 6],
   [4, 3]]
];

for (let [A, B] of ABs){
  console.log(`A: ${ A }`);
  console.log(`B: ${ B }`);
  console.log(f(A, B));
  console.log('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic. However, in the implementation, there is a small bug i.e. division by zero. You can add one more condition to mitigate the bug i.e. `if(t == A[i]) continue`.

Comment: @strikersps that fix wouldn't address if `B[i]` is zero. As far as I know, we can have `0 mod x, x != 0`, it's just zero. Meaning if `t - A[i]` equals zero we can still have the mod check as long as the modulus is positive.

Comment: @strikersps that said, handling for `B[i] == 0` is missing from this implementation.

Comment: Ya, I was talking about `B[i] == 0` missing implementation and to mitigate that you can add a an additional check using logical and before checking for `(A[i] - t) % B[i] == 0` condition.

Comment: @strikersps but `t == A[i]` is not related to `B[i] == 0`. The first one will not produce an error by itself. Only if `B[i]` is zero we can get division by zero.

Comment: Ya, you are absolutely right both are different conditions but with a small connection if I am correct. What if `A = {5, 5, 5, 5 ,5} and B = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: @strikersps true -- the condition that we would allow `B[i]` to be zero and still be valid is if `t == A[i]`. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented the solution in `python`, you can have a look here: https://github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/blob/master/Hacker-Earth/Number-of-Steps/number_of_steps.py

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it there are two ways to solve it.

1. Iterative algorithm with some logic (Which I will implement in Python)
2. You can use sets (feels like kind of cheating).

**The way the author probably meant you to do:**

Every time we will try to reach the minimal value of the list (or lower) with all the other items in the list. If all the items are the same we stop and return success, otherwise we keep going. If some of the items fall below 0 we stop.

```py
import math

num_of_nums = int(input())

a_s = list(map(int, input().split()))
b_s = list(map(int, input().split()))

operations = 0
m = min(a_s)
while not all([a_s[0] == tmp for tmp in a_s]):
    if m < 0:
        print(-1)
        exit(0)
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(a_s, b_s)):
        if b == 0 and m != a:
            print(-1)
            exit(0)
        elif b == 0 and m == a:
            continue

        operations_to_min = int(math.ceil((a - m) / b))
        operations += operations_to_min
        a_s[i] = a - operations_to_min * b
    m = min(a_s)
print(operations)
```

**The sets way:**

After reading the inputs we create a set of numbers that can be created from reducing each `b` from `a`, so for the example provided we get:

> [{1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 5, 7},...

Now we find the intersection set, and take the highest number from it.
After this number is found we count the number of operations to reach that number for each `a` and `b` pair.

```py
import functools
num_of_nums = int(input())

a_s = list(map(int, input().split()))
b_s = list(map(int, input().split()))

sets = [set([a - b * i for i in range(a // b + 1 if b > 0 else 1)]) for a, b in zip(a_s, b_s)]
res = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, sets)

if len(res) > 0:
    biggest_num = max(res)
    operations = 0
    for a, b in zip(a_s, b_s):
        if b > 0:
            operations += (a - biggest_num) // b
    print(operations)
else:
    print(-1)
```